# if not x in list do opposite of i want it to do

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and I want to get a certain element of that list and for that I use an input.

So if you see, I keep the value in `x`, and when I enter a value that exists in `coleccion` (my list), it does the opposite of what I want it to do: it prints `'registro no existe'` instead of showing me all the prints.

Here is the part of my code I want to fix:

```
elif opt == '2':
        show(coleccion)
        x = int(input('digite el meteorito que desea editar: '))-1
        if x in coleccion:
            print('Nombre: ',coleccion[x]['nombre'])
            print('Pais: ',coleccion[x]['pais'])
            print('Fecha: ',coleccion[x]['fecha'])
            print('Latitud: ',coleccion[x]['lat'])
            print('Longitud: ',coleccion[x]['lng'])
            print('Comentario: ',coleccion[x]['comentarios'])
        elif not x in coleccion:
            print('registro no existe')
            tecla()
```

Comment: Can you include an example of what is in "coleccion"?

Comment: edit content for clarity

Comment: elif x not in colleccion... swap the order of 'x' and 'not'

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, your code seems to be contradicting in some places.
Your `coleccion[x]['nombre']` line suggests that your `coleccion` is a list of dictionary (i.e. `[{"nombre":...},...]`), which contradicts with your line

```
x = int(input('digite el meteorito que desea editar: '))-1
if x in coleccion:
```

which sets `x` as an integer. Meaning that `x in coleccion` statement is checking if an integer is inside a list of dictionary, which does not make sense. I suspect that is the cause of your error.
Cheers :)